# Materializecss Datepicker isn't returning value to Angular 8 reactive form

Tags: angular, materialize

I'm using materializecss 1.0.0 in a Angular 8 project, and I'm having a problem.

I made a angular reactive form with a **datepicker** and a **formselect** inside, but the 'valueChanges' variable from formGroup is only triggered when **formselect** updates its value, but the **datepicker** value still the same.

> Important 1: I know there's a package called angular2-materialize but it only works on version 0.100
>
> Important 2: I'm trying to use materialize-css without JQuery, since it's now a optional package.

**form-request-card.component.html** (partial)

```html
[...]
<form [formGroup]="formDOM">          
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Datepicker para data inicial (start) -->
                <div class="form-group col s12">
                    <label>Data inicial</label>
                    <input #startinput class="form-control datepicker" formControlName="start" type="date">
                </div>
    
                <!-- Selector referente a metrica utilizada na analise dos dados (metric) -->
                <div class="form-group input-field col s12">
                    <select #metricinput class="form-control" formControlName="metric">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione o valor</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let metric of metricArray" [value]=metric>
                            {{metric}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Métrica</label>
                </div>
           </div>
</form>
[...]
```

**form-request-card.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

declare const M: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-request-card',
  templateUrl: './form-request-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-request-card.component.css']
})

export class FormRequestCardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('startinput', {static: true}) startInput: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('metricinput', {static: true}) metricInput: ElementRef;

  readonly title = "test";

  metricArray: string[];
  formDOM: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    this.metricArray = ["op1", "op2", "op3"];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formDOM = this._formBuilder.group({ start: [null], metric: [null] });
    this.formDOM.valueChanges.forEach( (value) => console.log(JSON.stringify(value)) );
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let pickerProperty = {
      autoClose: true, format: "yyyy-mm-dd", container: "body"
    };

    M.Datepicker.init(this.startInput.nativeElement, pickerProperty);
    M.FormSelect.init(this.metricInput.nativeElement, {});
  }
}
```

When valueChanges is triggered the console.log result is:

```
    {"start":null,"metric":"op1"}
```

Is there a 'angular way' to solve this?

Thanks for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `FormControl`s in the `FormGroup`, and skip the `ViewChild` solution completely.
You could create the `formDOM` like this:

```
this.formDOM = this._formBuild.group({
   start: new FormControl(null),
   metric: new FormControl(null),
})
```

and then get their values `onChange` or on some user action like this:

```
console.log(this.formDOM.controls['start'].value);
console.log(this.formDOM.controls['metric'].value);
```

Also the FormControls have their own onChange event, so you can subscribe to them independently with `this.formDOM.controls['start'].valueChanges` and `this.formDOM.controls['metric'].valueChanges`.

With this solution you can delete the `@ViewChild` lines from the .ts file and the `#startinput` and `#metricinput` parameters from your HTML

**NOTE:** another useful thing with the `FormControl`s is that you can use so called *validators* to make an input mandantory or restrict the possible values. The `FormControl` accept an array of validators (and other options) as a second paramter upon creation, similarly to this: `start: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])`  (`Validators` can be imported from `@angular/forms` and it contains a handful of basic validation methods but you can also write your own validator and use it across your components). Read more about this in the docs: [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) and [Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators)

Comment: Just to clarify: you will have to import the FormControl from @angular/forms as well